# iOS13.4.1 - XMLHTTPRequest cannot load error in beforeunload / unload event handlers

Tags: javascript, ios, xmlhttprequest

I am using XMLHTTPRequest to post the data in javascript. Upto iOS13.3.1 it is worked fine in safari, chorme browsers. When i update the device to latest OS iOS 13.4.1 then it is showing XMLHTTPRequest cannot load error in debug console for both safari, chrome browsers and the functionality is not working as expected.

While debugging found some pints, please check my observations below.

1. It is not failing for all requests, for some of them getting response status as 200. I am not sure is there anything changed specifically in iOS 13.4.1
2. In code i am using `request.open('POST', url, false)`

[image]

Can anyone please help me out.

Comment: is `XMLHTTPRequest cannot load` the full extent of the error? seems like a not very useful error - is it **all** XMLHttpRequests, or just some that fail?

Comment: It is not for all requests for some of them getting response status as 200. I am not sure is there anything changed specifically in iOS 13.4.1. added some extra points to my question, please check once.

Comment: I wonder if it's the synchronous requests that are failing in this way - can you see any obvious difference between the code that works and the code that fails?

Comment: I am using the same set of code for all the request. At some point it is stopping debugger and showing an error.

Comment: `request.open('POST', url, false)` so you are using deprecated synchronous XMLHttpRequest - it's been deprecated for many years, perhaps apple have decided (because chrome in apple isn't chrome as you know it) to finally disable syncrhonous XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

Finally i figured out the solution.

As per [reference webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=204912), we cann't perform `XMLHTTPRequest` synchronous calls in beforeunload / unload. So from iOS13.4 and above `XMLHTTPRequest` synchronous calls don't work in beforeunload / unload.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the below error:
Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http:***** due to access control checks.

just on connected mode I had a problem for ios 13.4.1

Comment: May i know how did you solve this issue, can you please add the code here. Is it solved the issue with your changes ?